# Change "this" context type in every method of interface

Tags: typescript, types

```
type Context = {anyContext: any};

interface Test {
   method1: (this: Context, a: number, b: number) => void;
   method2: (this: Context, x: string, y: string) => void;
}
```

Currently I've written this interface above, but I'd like to do something like this:

```
interface TestBase {
   method1: (a: number, b: number) => void;
   method2: (x: string, y: string) => void;
}

type Test2 = ChangeContextInEveryMethod<TestBase, Context>;
```

so types `Test` and `Test2` are equal.

Basically I need to change `this` type in every method of specific `interface`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where you [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) each function-typed property's arguments and return type and then produce a new such type with the [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) set to the desired type:

```
type ChangeContextInEveryMethod<T extends object, Th> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? 
    (this: Th, ...args: A) => R : 
    T[K]
}

type Test2 = ChangeContextInEveryMethod<TestBase, Context>;
/* type Test2 = {
    method1: (this: Context, a: number, b: number) => void;
    method2: (this: Context, x: string, y: string) => void;
} */
```

This works for your example.  There are certainly edge cases; for example, if your methods are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), the mapped type's method will not be generic.  So take care to make sure that your use cases are supported.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsKBeKBvKBDBEeJVYALn0KgF8BuAKHoEsSAnAMzwGNoAVCAM7ps9KFAC2EYAAs4AEwCMFABQymAisWRoANPgoIAruIBGEVnpMHjZ1gEpMAPigA3OEzkMxkmfIBMKmoasIjawHooFEKsLADmeiBRwDEIsQ4Yzm4eDNSMLMgc3HyCwABCeALQIt5SsooqeNam5pZNtumZ7p6iErX+KpFQ0XEJSSlpTq5dOYygkLDSBLEQWqQAkggAoi7mIACyfXIAPLxQpBAIcgJQcCYAVhBc4VC80s5Y1VAA2gDSUCxQADWEBAcHYLwAuhReL8IWc0BcrlBlAA6NF4VixYIsdjmKAAQQ6-wQuNYUAASlAAPzIoLQ6R6NEojFYiiEyaU6Gw+i5ehzYpCPyYBZLFahdZbHasfaHE4lcqVPSrNCOBgAegAVFB+S8SkKPj0ar56rTpOpNOLdPooEZmhYoFYbTZzESst0xEa6gFTeaQiQrYNhqlRkNknFXdMeVANWqgA)

Comment: I did not know you could `infer` multiple types in one `extends` expression, has that always been supported?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, since conditional types were introduced in TypeScript 2.8.